# Time Series Analysis

Tags: time-series, machine-learning

I have attended a lecture about introduction to machine learning at my university (SVM, regression, kernels etc.). Now I'm planning to do a project where machine learning knowledge is needed. In fact I would have to use time series analysis. A reference to the book "Time Series Analysis" written by Hamilton, James Douglas (Princeton University Press) is given. The book is not online and I'm currently not close to a library so I cannot look into the book.

I've never heard about time series analysis before. Is it similar to basic machine learning topics I've heard about or is it very difficult?

Comment: I would say yes, I found it to be difficult.  Time series study is a separate course at my Uni at the PhD level for economists.  I would have preferred it as two semesters

Comment: If you're embarking upon a project that requires the application of Time Series Analysis yet you don't know what it is and the reference you have is Hamilton then you're probably not going to have an easy time! What sort of deadline are you working under? It could be difficult, but it depends on your background and what particular aspect or class of time-series models that you need to work with; some are straight-forward, others not so much.

Comment: It is the following master thesis: http://control.ee.ethz.ch/index.cgi?page=sada;action=details;id=539 I have 6 month time. I have knowledge about what is mentioned in the description (linear regression, kernel regression, SVM), but I'm really worried about the reference to time series analysis. I only attented an introduction course in machine learning and a lab in machine learning (supervised and unsupervised learning) but I was never in touch with time series analysis.

Comment: Interesting thesis. I'd say check out the following online book, which will give an introduction to various types of methods and models in time-series analysis. https://www.otexts.org/fpp I hope this puts you on the right road and that others can also recommend the book as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you Graeme Walsh. The online book looks pretty nice and not very hard to understand. Is the book "Time Series Analysis" from Hamilton really that hard to read / understand? It is around 700 pages, so perhaps a bit much to read it all for the thesis. To present it in proper light: I find the topic and also machine learning in general very interesting but I have fear that if it turns out that time series analysis is too hard that I would fail because I cannot assess if it would be too hard right now. There are other topics for my thesis which would be easy (not ML) but not that interesting

Comment: To be honest, these are concerns that you should relay to your supervisor. My own personal opinion would be that it would take a single course during one semester to get through (the topics in) Hamilton - and additional time-series texts. You could, of course, plough through the book, skipping the majority of the details, quite quickly, but I'm not sure how useful that would be. Hamilton is generally regarded as a decent text for reference, but not so much for learning from. It is also a bit dated at this stage.

Comment: Ok, I will discuss it with my supervisor. Can you recommend a book (or online course or paper) about Time Series Analysis which is more compact and easier than Hamilton and goes beyond the online book you provided above?